# Aggregation that returns the users name and id?

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using ES and the Rails [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#aggregations)

I am using aggregations to build search filters like this:

```rb
{
  aggs: {
    user_id: {},
    user: {},
  }
}
```

I can just run a query based on a link from the `user` result like `?user=Dan%20Tappin` but ideally I would like the link to display `Dan Tappin` with the link to `?user_id=1`.

Can I get the aggs to return something like this:

```rb
{
  "buckets" => [
    { "key" => "Dan Tappin", "id" => "1", "doc_count" => 307 },
  ]
}
```

I know that I can build a custom mapping like `first_name + " " + last_name + "+++" + id` and then parse the agg afterwards to get the name / id out. Just looking to see if there is a more elegant method.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is probably going to be pre-defining them as you've said yourself. The alternative without touching mappings would be to add a nested top-hits aggregation, I'm not too sure about the syntax with Searchkick, but it will be something among those lines to build it:

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will top-k `user_ids` and and top1 document per each `user_id`, so you could combine result from top hits aggregation to get user details together with doc_count from the terms aggregation.